# How to implement centered recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

How can I implement this kind of recyclerview (or ViewPager) in the image below on my own.

[image]

I tried https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView library. But it has bugs.

Comment: Does this help - [Carousal View](https://github.com/jama5262/CarouselView) , or instead of depending upon library you can create your own view - [paging image carousel](https://medium.com/holler-developers/paging-image-gallery-with-recyclerview-f059d035b7e7)

Comment: `But it has bugs.` - what kind of bugs

Answer (score 0):

To snap item to center after scrolling `LinearSnapHelper` is used.

Full code is follow in kotlin

```
val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView)
yourRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
  override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            val centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(mLayoutManager)
            centerView?.let {
               val visiblePosition = mLayoutManager.getPosition(it)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. I will try to implement it and tell you the result

Comment: Bro. I didn't use this answer for implementing the recyclerview in the image that I posted, where the image in the center is greater than the other two. Because I think that making the scale of centeredview greater than the others with animation seemed somehow difficult. But for another same sized recyclerview, your answer has been definetely helpful for detecting center view. Anyway, thanks.